# pyspark df filter records based on integer

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Input:

[image]

Expected Output:

[image]

These columns are dynamic. there can be 'n' number of columns. Need to filter records by all columns which is not equal to 0. Column datatype is decimal.

```
for column in df.columns:
  count=(df.filter(F.col(column) != int(0)).count()
  if count>0:
     do some function
  else:
     do some other function
```

Main problems i face:

- Any way to filter all columns at the same time without for loop
- NULL records are not filtering out

How this can be efficiently done in pyspark?

Comment: sorry..corrected..

Comment: Your question is unclear. From your expected output I gather you want to filter out rows where all columns are equal to 0? Your sample code seems to be doing something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a filter expression dynamically for all the columns and then perform your filter.

```
filter_condition = ''
for column_name in df.schema.names:
  if filter_condition != '':
    filter_condition +=' & '
  filter_condition +=  f"{column_name} <> 0"

display(df.filter(filter_condition))
```

This one uses simple sql syntax.